# How to use if statements based on DropdownButton values in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three drop boxes
The first DropboxButton is called the sex_controller, which contains two values: male and female
The second DropboxButton is the male_weight_controller, which has values of -64, -70, -76, +82
The third DropboxButton is the female_weight_controller, which has values of -43, -48, -53, +58
It's in the form of a String

I want male_weight_controller if the value of sex_controller is male, and female_weight_controller if the value of sex_controller is female

```
late String sex_value;

sex_controller(
            onSelected: (String value){
               sex_value = value;
              },
            ),
```

```
if(sex_value == 'male' || sex_value.isEmpty)
           male_weight_controller(
             onSelected: (String value){
               weight_value = value;
             }
           ),
if(sex_value == 'female')
            female_weight_controller(
             onSelected: (String value){
                weight_value = value;
             }
            ),
```

error : `======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following LateError was thrown building: LateInitializationError: Local 'sex_value' has not been initialized.`

How can you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message mentioned if your variable sex_value is a LateInitializationError, which means it hasn't been initialized before it is being used. you could fix this issue, by making sure that sex_value is initialized before it is used in the if conditions.

```
String sex_value = 'male'; // Initialize sex_value with a default value

sex_controller(
  onSelected: (String value){
    setState(() {
      sex_value = value;
    });
  },
),

if(sex_value == 'male' || sex_value.isEmpty)
  male_weight_controller(
    onSelected: (String value){
      setState(() {
        weight_value = value;
      });
    }
  ),
if(sex_value == 'female')
  female_weight_controller(
    onSelected: (String value){
      setState(() {
        weight_value = value;
      });
    }
  ),
```